# What is the WinHttpAutoProxySvc?

Tags: windows, windows-service

What is the WinHttpAutoProxySvc ?

Is it involved in the Windows Updating system?

Is it ever used in any way if there is no proxy server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This service is what provides the [autoproxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa384240.aspx) service in Windows. If you are not using proxy autoconfig, then you can safely disable this service.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, this utility provides the autoproxy service in a Windows Server installation. It’s really only relevant to you if you’re using automatic proxy configuration. Otherwise, you can safely disable it. If you have additional questions, I'd check out [Everything You Need To Know About WinHttpAutoProxySvc](https://www.libertycenterone.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-winhttpautoproxysvc-and-four-other-essential-windows-services-for-administrators/).